# Old ReplicaSet and Old pods are still alive with New ReplicaSet and New pods when using command 'kubectl replace -f [yaml file]'

Tags: kubernetes

**What happened**:

Old ReplicaSet and Old pods are still alive with New ReplicaSet and New pods when using command 'kubectl replace -f [yaml file]'

**What you expected to happen**:

The old ReplicaSet should be scale down to 0 and the old pods will be deleted.

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible)**:

The difference between the 2 yaml files. The new yaml file has:

1. Add `component: propel-sx` in spec.template.metadata.labels
2. Add affinity section in spec.template.spec.affinity

   ```
   affinity:
   podAntiAffinity:
     preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
     - weight: 100
       podAffinityTerm:
         labelSelector:
           matchExpressions:
           - key: component
             operator: In
             values:
             - propel-sx
         topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
     - weight: 100
       podAffinityTerm:
         labelSelector:
           matchExpressions:
           - key: workLoad
             operator: In
             values:
             - ExtraHigh
         topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
   ```

**Anything else we need to know?**:

I found a strange thing that the old ReplicaSet will lose the field 'ownerReferences'. I think this field will be used to connect the old ReplicaSet and the new ReplicaSet. Scale down the old pod and scale up the new pod. But I don't know why the field 'ownerReferences' lost.

**Environment**:
- Kubernetes version (use `kubectl version`):

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.6", GitCommit:"9f8ebd171479bec0ada837d7ee641dec2f8c6dd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-21T15:21:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

- OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release):
  CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
- Kernel (e.g. `uname -a`):

`Linux shc-sma-cd75.hpeswlab.net 3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon May 21 23:36:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Could you please share the whole Yaml file for your ReplicaSet or Deployment?

Comment: Yes. You can find the 2 yaml files here. https://github.com/cainzhong/yaml-compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE that `kubectl replace` destroys the object and creates a new one in its place. This might cause the replica sets (which are 'children' of the 'Deployment' object) to be left behind and no longer assumed to belong to any deployment at all. In theory, this could be mitigated by explicitly specifying a label selector that the Deployment uses to find which pods are its own (see [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) here), but it is probably best to use `kubectl apply` instead, so that your deployment is updated rather than deleted and re-made (this will preserve the label selectors that are automatically set up by k8s if you haven't set any).

I assume that you want the default 'rolling upgrade' behavior of Deployments: they create a new replica set and start it before the old one is drained (rolling upgrade). If not: to change this, add

```
strategy:
    type: Recreate
```

in the deployment spec. This will make the old replica set get drained before the new one is started.

Comment: No. We need to use the strategy 'RollingUpdate' to minimize the downtime.

Comment: You may want to edit your question - it appears that you see having the old replicaSet and the new one at the same time as a problem. However, this is how the Deployment object actually does rolling upgrade. It creates the new replica set first and starts adding instances to it, while it drains the old one. In fact, it does not delete old replica sets at all, but keeps several historic ones forever, so as to allow for a quick 'undo' of an upgrade (in essence, keeping a record of your old configurations). You can set how many historic replicasets there will be in a deployment.

Comment: My problem is not the old ReplicaSet exists. It is alive. The DESIRED, CURRENT, READY should become 0 for the old ReplicaSet. But it doesn't in my environment. So the old pods also cannot be terminated automatically.

Comment: @Cain, it is not clear, are your old and new ReplicaSets in the READY state at the same time?

Comment: @Golenyaev, I don't see the READY state in the old and new ReplicaSets. But the old and new Pod are all RUNNING and READY.

Comment: Thanks, Leo K. The problem is solved cause of missing a label selector of the Deployment.